# MySQL conditional query

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I've got file names stored in two fields in a table. The fields are called file1 an file2.

file1 is ALWAYS present. file2 might not be present for some rows.

I want to write a query that would get me only a certain extension of files from the DB.

For that I am using for example

```
...WHERE file1 LIKE '%jpg%'
```

But here I cannot use `AND file2 LIKE '%jpg%'`  because file2 may be empty, which is ok.

So what do I do so that the LIKE condition is only applied when the field is not empty?

Comment: note that file1 LIKE '%jpg%' will match 'hbjpgx.gif'.  Unless you're absolutely certain that won't happen, you might want to make it LIKE '%.jpg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `AND (file2 is NULL or file2 LIKE %jpg%)`

Comment: It looks like you're missing quotes around `%jpg%` :)

Answer (score 2):

Make use of parenthesis to clarify.

```
WHERE file1 LIKE '%jpg%' AND (file2 LIKE '%jpg%' OR file2 is NULL OR file2 = '')
```

or whatever other conditions you need from file2

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AND (file2 LIKE '%jpg%' OR file2 IS NULL (or file2 = '' depending on what your empty value is) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    files 
WHERE   file1 LIKE '%jpg' AND 
        (file2 LIKE '%jpg' OR file2 IS NULL);
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE files (file1 varchar(20), file2 varchar(20));

INSERT INTO files VALUES ('pic1.jpg', NULL);
INSERT INTO files VALUES ('pic2.png', NULL);
INSERT INTO files VALUES ('pic3.jpg', 'otherpic.jpg');
INSERT INTO files VALUES ('pic4.png', 'nopic.jpg');
INSERT INTO files VALUES ('pic5.bmp', 'otherpic.gif');
```

Returns:

```
+----------+--------------+
| file1    | file2        |
+----------+--------------+
| pic1.jpg | NULL         |
| pic3.jpg | otherpic.jpg |
+----------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use just use `OR file2 LIKE '%jpg%'`?

Comment: No.  That would get him File1 even if it had the wrong extenstion.

Comment: BOTH the files should have the same extension. Using OR would return rows where the extension is not jpg in one file name.